# Undefined method 'save' for nil Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm completely new on Rails. I'm trying to learn it by building a forum following a video on youtube.

However, I'm stuck in a error and just have no idea how to solve it. I keep getting "undefined method 'save' for nil.

The code:

**Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new[post_params]

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Saved"
    redirect_to action: :show
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was a problem adding"
    render action: :new
  end
end

def post_params
  params[:post].permit(:title, :content)
end
```

**new.html.haml**

```
%h1 New post

= render 'form'
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
= f.input :title
= f.input :content
= f.submit
```

**CreatePosts**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong here?

Comment: `@post = Post.new[post_params]` should be `@post = Post.new(post_params)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the `new` method correctly (read the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)).

Change this :

```
@post = Post.new[post_params]
```

To this :

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

Comment: and change the typo at  strong params as well ^_^